# Fit page contents fit in iphone, android screen with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I hava a HTML page on server. consider an article example is loaded in that HTML page. and i open that page from my android and iphone mobile's browsers.

The page contains a description and images and links in it.
and problem is that image inside that page is outside from the screen.

i want to know that there is any way to fit all the resources (description, image, links) should be set inside the page with javascript.

Comment: You are talking about a mobile layout, and you should do it in CSS, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to css file:

@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px)
{

/*--- iPhone only CSS here:re-style your image in order to make it fit in your iphone/android ---*/

}

you can read more at http://csswizardry.com/2010/01/iphone-css-tips-for-building-iphone-websites/

Answer (score 1):

On my mobile site I used a meta tag to keep everything inside the screen.

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width">
```

I think this should do the trick. Make sure to place it within the `<head>` tag.

Hope this helps.